# Applying CQRS to a sample workflow

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Let's say I have a task management application that uses the CQRS paradigm. How would I apply it to the following:

Scenario: As a user I want to create a task.

Java Pseudo Code:

```
interface Command {}
class CreateTaskCommand implements Command {
    public String taskId;
    public String description;
    public boolean complete;
}

interface CommandHandler<Command> {
    public void execute(Command command);
}
class CreateTaskHandler implements CommandHandler<CreateTaskCommand> {
    public void execute(CreateTaskCommand cmd) {
        validateTask(cmd);
        repository.storeTask(new Task(cmd.taskId, cmd.description, cmd.complete));
    }
}
```

Given the above code, where does the Event, EventHandler and Aggregate Root come into play (how would I proceed for the given story)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is a bit too wide in scope, you probably want to read up on CQRS and DDD first and then ask questions showing the code you have so-far and where you're having problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A command handler typically delegates behavior to an aggregate root which it loads with a repository. In turn, an aggregate root raises an event in response to the invoked action, such as `TaskCreatedEvent`. There are various flavors of event handlers. You can have an event handler who's sole job is to dispatch published events to external systems. External systems will subscribe to published events with an event handler which will typically invoke a command in response to the event. An event handler can also be used to invoke additional domain logic in response to the event within the local context.

Comment: In the case of a CreateTaskCommand I would be using the repository to store or add the Task (aggregate root) and then apply an Event, TaskCreatedEvent. 

    repository.add (task);
    eventHandler.apply (taskCreatedEvent);

Is this the proper way?